# SQL - double column used from primary key with autoincrement

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, auto-increment

I am user the following as primary key in the SqlDB:

I am doing the Index as Autoincrement, but it is autoincremented in general not per user.
Example userid=1,index=1, then insert another for userid=2 then inserted userid=2index=2
Then we insert a new entry for userid=2 theninserted userid=2 index=3 and not 1.

Is it possible to do what I want?

Comment: Yoav - It is not clear what you want to do.  What do you want to happen?

Comment: What RDBMS and version?

Comment: Hey - RDBMS - what is it? I want to have a primary key userId,Index - Index autoincremented - should be 0..N for each userId

Comment: I think I did not put the index as the PK..... Maybe that is the cause. missed it

Comment: RDMBS is the database.  Is it MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostGres?

Comment: Then unless you are using SQL Server 2012 there's no "good" way to do this.

Comment: OK Thanks... Will have to manage it as it is

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than one IDENTITY column per a table.
Use MAX(index)+1 where userid=X, when inserting a new row without auto-increment.

Comment: I guess there is a function needs to be created in the SQL Table. Unfortunatly I have no idea how to do this. Am I right? Can you explain a bit or send a link ?

Comment: The first part is true; the second part is fraught with peril unless the race condition is eliminated through the use of locking hints or error handling.

Comment: The OP doesn't want more than one IDENTITY columns. My interpretation from the confusing description is that he needs a column `(identityID)` which is not Unique but the combination `(userID,identityID)` to be Unique.